# How to convert asyncio.sleep seconds to 1 minute or 1 hour by multiplying on Discord.py 3.6

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time: int=None, arg1=None, *, arg2=None):
  if not member:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description=f"Please **mention** a **member**.", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/exclamation-mark_2757.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
 if not time:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="Please **provide** a **time**.", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/exclamation-mark_2757.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
 if not arg1:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description=f"Please **provide** a **time unit**.", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/exclamation-mark_2757.png")
    embed.set_footer(text="Help: minutes = minute(s) | hours = hour(s.)")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
 if not arg2: 
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description=f"Please **provide** a **reason**.", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/exclamation-mark_2757.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
await ctx.message.delete()
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
await member.add_roles(role)
embed=discord.Embed(title="MUTE", description=f"Successfully muted **{member.name}**.", color=0x00ff08)
embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/muted-speaker_1f507.png")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
if arg1 == minutes:
    time=time * 60
elif arg1 == hours:
    time=time * 3600  
channel = await member.create_dm()
embed=discord.Embed(title="MUTED", description=f"You have been muted in **Everest Studios.** \n 
**Reason:** {arg2}. \n **Time:** {time} {arg1}.", color=0xff0000)
embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/muted-speaker_1f507.png")
await channel.send(embed=embed)
await asyncio.sleep(time)
await member.remove_roles(role)
embed=discord.Embed(title="MUTED", description="You have been unmuted in **Everest Studios.**", color=0x00ff08)
embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/twitter/259/speaker-high-volume_1f50a.png")
final = await member.create_dm()
await final.send(embed=embed)
```

So i have no idea why the code "if arg1 == minutes:..." is not working, it like blocks the rest of the code depending on where its positioned. Is there any way or any other code i could possibly use to convert the given int into minutes/hours? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested out if this also works with multiplication, but I think so.

So what you are doing, is trying to redefine the variable while using it (what can cause in some cases some errors). What my guess is what should work, is for example

```
if arg1 == minutes:
    time *= 60
```